# Mac OSX Convert library (html file to pdf) works via terminal but not PHP

Tags: php, macos, terminal, pdf-generation, passthru

I'm trying to take a generated html file and convert it to PDF on the fly with PHP.
It's going on my localhost and staying there so for the PDF conversion I'm using a Mac OSX utility, I guess you would call it.

The terminal command being:

```
/System/Library/Printers/Libraries/convert -f temporary.html -o destination/final.pdf
```

This works properly via terminal (produces a simple 20kb PDF file); however, when I run it inside PHP via passthru() the file (final.pdf) is created though it is a Zero KB file (corrupt).

The /destination folder is CHMOD 777, temporary.html is CHMOD 755.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit (Additional Detail):
Now in the error log, amongst the debug lines there is an error of "ERROR: xhtmltopdf (PID 13204) crashed on signal 6!"

Comment: It's clear it's not a permissions issue since the file gets created. Does php show any error in its (or apache's) log file? Maybe the temporary html isn't accessible, for instance.

Comment: There are only references to a missing favicon. //Edit: Now there is an error after running a few more times: "xhtmltopdf (PID 13165) crashed on signal 6"

Comment: is your path to the source html correct? you might need to provide a full absolute path, depending on where your php script is.

Comment: The conversion likely uses Quartz, which means you need a windowserver connection.  So, you either need to run `convert` as the logged-in user, or use something else to convert HTML to PDF (perhaps http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ ?)

Comment: @Nicholas. That should be placed as an answer

Comment: never really sure what to do when the question is underspecified...

Answer (score 0):

I like to share what I do to generate PDF file on the fly. We use UNIX server to host.

I use tcpdf - a php library to convert HTML to PDF file. I use it in my projects and it works very well. TCPDF supports css, javascript, forms, images and lot more.

Website: http://www.tcpdf.org/

Demos: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

Comment: A little bulky/overcomplicated for what I need I think. I simply need to take an existing HTML file and convert it.

Answer (score 0):

When I need convert HTML in PDF I use this very nice software: http://www.princexml.com

You could have a look, it's free for personal use.